# How can pattern matching be done on text?

Tags: elixir

Lets say that I want to pattern match against text. Specifically, I want to pattern match on the first letter.

For example, how do I create a pattern that would match "about" and "analog" but not "beta"?

I've tried this:

```
defmodule MatchStick do
    def doMatch([head | tail]) when head == "a" do 1 end
    def doMatch([head | tail]) do 0 end
end

res = MatchStick.doMatch("abcd");
```

I've also tried character lists:

```
defmodule MatchStick do
    def doMatch([head | tail]) when head == 'a' do 1 end
    def doMatch([head | tail]) do 0 end
end

res = MatchStick.doMatch('abcd');
```

Neither worked. What is the proper way to match text?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
defmodule MatchStick do
  def doMatch("a" <> rest) do 1 end
  def doMatch(_) do 0 end
end
```

You need to use the string concatenation operator seen [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#binaries-and-bitstrings)

Example:

```
iex> "he" <> rest = "hello"
"hello"
iex> rest
"llo"
```

Comment: And how about this: start <> "ell" <> end = "hello" ?

Answer (score 22):

In Elixir, single quoted strings are quite different from double quoted strings. Single quoted strings are basically lists of integers, where each integer represents a character. Therefore, they are also called character lists. They are mainly used for compatibility with Erlang, because that's how Erlang strings work. You can use single quoted strings just like you would use lists:

```
iex> hd('a')
97

iex> [97 | rest] = 'abcd'
'abcd'
iex> rest
'bcd'

iex> [97, 98 | rest] = 'abcd'
'abcd'
iex> rest
'cd'

iex> 'ab' ++ rest = 'abcd'
'abcd'
iex> rest
'cd'
```

The match function for single quoted strings would look like this:

```
def match('a' ++ rest), do: 1
def match(_), do: 0
```

Elixir will hide the list from you and display it as a string, when all of the integers represent valid characters. To trick Elixir into showing you the internal representation of a character list, you can insert a `0`, which is an invalid character:

```
iex> string = 'abcd'
'abcd'
iex> string ++ [0]
[97, 98, 99, 100, 0]
```

However, one would typically use double quoted strings in Elixir, because these handle UTF-8 correctly, are much easier to work with and are used by all internal Elixir modules (for example the useful `String` module). Double quoted strings are binaries, so you can treat them as any other binary type:

```
iex> <<97, 98, 99, 100>>
"abcd"
iex> <<1256 :: utf8>>
"Ө"

iex> <<97>> <> rest = "abcd"
"abcd"
iex> rest
"bcd"

iex> "ab" <> rest = "abcd"
"abcd"
iex> rest
"cd"
```

The match function for double quoted strings would look like this:

```
def match("a" <> rest), do: 1
def match(_), do: 0
```

Elixir will hide the internal representation of binary strings as well. To reveal it, you can again insert a `0`:

```
iex> string = "abcd"
"abcd"
iex> string <> <<0>>
<<97, 98, 99, 100, 0>>
```

Lastly, to convert between single quoted strings and double quoted strings you can use the functions `to_string` and `to_charlist`:

```
iex> to_string('abcd')
"abcd"
iex> to_charlist("abcd")
'abcd'
```

To detect them, you can use `is_list` and `is_binary`. These also work in guard clauses.

```
iex> is_list('abcd')
true
iex> is_binary('abcd')
false
iex> is_list("abcd")
false
iex> is_binary("abcd")
true
```

For example, to make the double quoted version compatible with single quoted strings:

```
def match(str) when is_list(str), do: match(to_string(str))
def match("a" <> rest), do: 1
def match(_), do: 0
```

Comment: I have a question about this line of code: "iex> [97 | rest] = 'abcd'" I understand why it works, but it isn't very readable. Is there a way to do something similar to this "iex> ['a' | rest] = 'abcd'"?

Comment: Thats why I added an example with the list concatenation operator `++`. Alternatively convert to binary string :-)

Comment: @epotter: `[?a | rest] = 'abcd'`

Comment: why is it not possible to do `prefix <> "cd" = "abcd"`. It return `a binary field without size is only allowed at the end of a binary pattern`. Is there any alternative to do so

Comment: @RohanPujari as the error says this is not possible with pattern matching. The reason is that checking the head of a list is a cheap operation, while checking the end of a list is expensive due to the way lists and binaries are implemented in Erlang/Elixir. The language authors are trying to make it easy to do cheap operations, and hard to use expensive operations. Your best option is to consume the string until you reach the end while aggregating the previous values, then compare the end with your desired string.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickOscity for pointing out the reason why they are not supported. I think regex will solve my purpose. I just wanted to match string with regex and return true and false, but was just checking whether it was possible with pattern matching

Answer (score 12):

Just in case someone needed. If you need to match on the part of the string that is in the known middle and you aware of its length then you can use binary matching:

```sh
iex(1)> <<"https://", locale::binary-size(2), ".wikipedia.com" >> = "https://en.wikipedia.com" 
"https://en.wikipedia.com"
iex(2)> locale
"en"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pattern match on the head of a charlist, there's one slight difference you need to make in your second code snippet.

`'a'` is actually a charlist with one element, so comparing with the head of a charlist will always be false. A charlist is really a list of integer values:

```
iex> 'abcd' == [97, 98, 99, 100]
true
```

The char `a` equates to integer `97`. You can get the integer code of a character in Elixir by preceding it with a `?`, so:

```
iex> ?a == 97
true
iex> ?a == hd('a')
true
```

So in your guard clause, you'll want to match `head == ?a`, or more simply:

```
defmodule MatchStick do
    def doMatch([?a | _tail]), do: 1
    def doMatch(_), do: 0
end
```